# check if either of two substrings exist in a string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am using the following code to replace all `-` and remove all `,` from my dataframe columns

```
df[['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars']]=df[['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars']].applymap(lambda r: np.nan if '-' in str(r) else str(r).replace(',', ''))
```

There are some columns which are `"nan"` (not np.nan but just string nan). To remove those as well, I do

```
useless_strings=['-','nan']
df[['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars']]=df[['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars']].applymap(lambda r: np.nan if any(xx in str(r) for xx in useless_strings) else str(r).replace(',', ''))
```

This does not remove those `"nan"` strings. What's wrong?

Comment: *This does not remove those "nan" strings. What's wrong?* What was the output?

Comment: By the way there are no list comprehensions in your code

Comment: @DaniMesejo, I want to replace all `-` and `"nan"` by `np.nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True` by substrings defined in dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['10,4','-','nan',5,'kkk-oo']],
                  columns=['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars'])
print (df)
  sale_price mrp discount  ratings   stars
0       10,4   -      nan        5  kkk-oo


useless_strings=['-','nan']
d = dict.fromkeys(useless_strings, np.nan)
d[','] = ''
print (d)
{'-': nan, 'nan': nan, ',': ''}

cols = ['sale_price','mrp', 'discount', 'ratings', 'stars']
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(d, regex=True)
print (df)
  sale_price  mrp  discount  ratings  stars
0        104  NaN       NaN        5    NaN
```

Comment: @AmanArora - yes, it working like need.

Comment: I want to replace the string with `np.nan` if it contains `"-"` or `"nan"`

Comment: @AmanArora - Answer was edited.